# Julia Dataframe generate unlinked variable duplicate

Tags: dataframe, julia

I want to define a new column based on a which is afterwards not linked to the original.

```
using DataFrames
x = DataFrame(a=1:3)
x.b = x.a
x.b[1] += 1
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several ways to do it, the major are:

```
x[:, :b] = x.a
```

or

```
x.b = x[:, :a]
```

You can also write:

```
x[!, :b] = x[:, :a]
```

(this can be useful if `:b` were a variable)

Finally you could also just write:

```
df.b = copy(df.a)
```

or

```
df.b = df.a[:]
```

All indexing rules for DataFrames.jl can be found at https://juliadata.github.io/DataFrames.jl/stable/lib/indexing/.

In short (simplifying a bit but these rules are enough to know in practice):

- `df.col` is non-copying for getting and for setting a column
- `df[!, :col]` is the same as `df.col` with the difference that you can then easily use a variable instead of a literal for indexing and it works with broadcasting while `df.col` does not work with broadcasting if `:col` were not present in a data frame
- `df[:, :col]` copies for getting a column and is an in-place operation for setting a column, unless `:col` is not present in `df` in which case it freshly allocates it when setting